# Disable csrf protection not working

Tags: php, rest, api, symfony, csrf

I am working on a PHP based API using symfony framework (2.6.x), I have csrf token protection enabled and everything is working fine with an angularjs frontend. Now I want to use the same api within an Android app. But the POST Calls are returning Bad token exception. Or even if I am calling a simple POST endpoint using postman.

I have tried different solutions and followed many questions on stackoverflow regarding this but they're either asking if its good to disable or not. I dont want to disable it but either make it available for a specific role or disable on a specific endpoints that have the same root.

Like there is a check in fos configuration,

```
fos_rest:
    disable_csrf_role: ROLE_API
```

I have assigned this role to a user, but still the same error (403 forbidden with detailed message: Bad CSRF Token)

Comment: Don't know if can be useful, but you can disable csrf on the single form.

Comment: I thought of this, and already disabled for a single form. But the problem is that it even returns the error even before hitting the controller. So no matter what form you're using and if its protected or not.